# Subscribing on ReplaySubject doesn't work

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this on my authentication

```
public currentUser: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
```

when user login i use

```
  public setCurrentUser(user: User) {
    this.currentUser.next(user);
  }
```

to set the user object.

The problem exists on `CanActivateGuard`, I think it not see the `currentUser` somehow

this is the code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

import {User} from '../models/user';


@Injectable()
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {
  private logged: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public _auth: AuthService
  ) {
    console.log('CanActivateGuard');

    this._auth.currentUser.subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this.logged = user.logged;
        console.log('user');
        console.log(user);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  public canActivate() {

    if ( !this.logged ) {
       this.router.navigate( [ 'login' ] );
    }
    console.log(this.logged);
    return this.logged;
  }
}
```

It never reach `this.logged = user.logged;` I think it see this._auth.currentUser as empty

This is the link of the whole project: https://github.com/MoustafaElkady/You360-Web-Client/tree/master/src/app

Comment: Why not return an observable from `canActivate`? Then you're not reliant on `this.logged` already having been set, which it might not be.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: `return this._auth.currentUser...`.

Comment: from canActivate? i think it must be boolean?

Comment: this._auth.currentUser return full object how would i know is it logged or not?

Comment: Please read up on rxjs observables and the Angular router. You can `map` or `pluck` to get a specific value from the current user.

Comment: can you provide me full answer please?

Answer (score 4):

[`canActivate`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) can return `Observable<boolean>`, which makes life more straightforward. You don't need to subscribe to the service's subject in the constructor, you can build an observable and let the router subscribe to the result.

```ts
@Injectable()
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService,
  ) { }

  public canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.currentUser
        .map(user => user.logged)  // extract logged property from user
        .catch(() => Observable.of(false))  // assume not logged in if error
        .do(loggedIn => {
          if (!loggedIn) {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);  // navigate if not logged in
          }
        }); 
  }
}
```

I'd recommend reading the [appropriate documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards); it's quite long, but there's a lot going on in the router.

I'd also recommend not making the subject itself `public` from the service; that means other things could push data into it. I wrote a blog post on using a private subject and public observable you may find useful: [*Handling data with the Angular AsyncPipe*](http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html).

Comment: @UnixMan if you're going to give that little information, it's really not worth commenting. What does *"didn't work"* mean; what happened instead? Can you give a [mcve]? Is there actually a user object available from the currentUser subject? Have you tried any logging/debugging? And so on.

Comment: yes, console.log(this._auth) in the guard always give me the service before user loggedd it, the default of, but when i make console.log(this._auth) in any component it gives me the right one, why the guard no seeing the service after logging please take a fast look here https://github.com/MoustafaElkady/You360-Web-Client/tree/master/src/app

Comment: @UnixMan again, give a [mcve]. [Edit] the question. Add context and your attempts to debug. Use the Plunkr from Angular as a starting point: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html. It's not ok to expect people to trawl through your repo to figure it out.

Comment: thank you for you time, one last thing .. is that guard set correctly here https://github.com/MoustafaElkady/You360-Web-Client/blob/master/src/app/web/web-routing.module.ts because the injected auth service always the default of before logging in